# An example of graded rings

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $I$ an ideal in $R$.
Then, we have a graded ring $R_{\ast}:= \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} I^n$, where $I^0=R$.

So, let $A$ be a polynomial ring with a valuable $x$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and set $A_{\ast}:=A\oplus (x) \oplus (x^2) \oplus (x^3) \oplus \cdots$, where $(x)$ is the ideal generated by $x$.

Then, $A_{\ast}$ is a graded ring, but I confused because how do we check
$(x^n)(x^m)\subset (x^{n+m})$ in $A_{\ast}$ ? (Of course,  $(x^n)(x^m)\subset (x^{n+m})$ in $A$.)

Moreover, the element $x\in A_{\ast}$, we have two expressions:

$x+0+0+\cdots = x = 0+x+0+\cdots$

Thank you.

Comment: The "in $A_*$" thing doesnt really matter. All that matters is that, as sets, $(x^n)(x^m)\subset (x^{n+m})$. The definition of graded ring doesn't require you check this "in $A_*$".

Comment: Also, if you *wanted* to check it in context of $A_*$, you use the fact that every element has a unique representation $a=a_0+a_1+a_2+\ldots$ where $a_i$ lives in the homogeneous component of degree $i$. In this case, $x$ has degree $1$, so we can only write $x$ as $x=0+x+0+\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

In the definition, a ring $A=\oplus _{n\geq 0}A_n$ (as aberian groups ) is a graded ring if $A_mA_n\subset A_{m+n}$. 

But the product $A_nA_m$ is taken in $A$ but not in $A_0$.

Comment: @sola the product in $A_0$ is the restriction of the product in $A$, so the distinction doesn't really matter.

Comment: In $A_*$, there are two elements $x$, one of degree $0$ and one of degree $1$, and they are not the same.  I find it helpful to define the Rees ring via $R_*=\oplus_{n\ge 0} I^nt^n$, where $t$ is an indeterminate of degree $1$.  With this definition, your $A_*$ has $x$ of degree $0$ and $xt$ of degree $1$.